Setting up an Energy Analyzer using Modbus
I am working on a setting up a Janitza Energy Analyzer UMG96S using RS485 cable connections via RS485 to USB converter. At first i was unable to communicate with the analyzer but after selecting the right Register types, baud rate etc. i was starting receiving some data. Cutting things short, Line to Neutral voltage Modbus Address is 200 and the list goes on further. I am getting correct values from analyzer with the help of suitable coefficients of "0.5" and "0.01". The values require are ranging from modbus address 200 to 212 and 270 to 278 and lastly 416.
Actual values at address 200 to 212 are perfectly fine but as soon as i select address 279 to 278 along with them, all the correct values become instantly wrong. And just removing 270 to 278 range modbus address all becomes perfect again.
And if i select only 270 to 278 range modbus address, their values are correct and if add a single address of 200 to 212 range all becomes wrong.
Using Modpoll and Datalogger Software (Sungrow Logger 1000A) I am getting the same result. In Modpoll I am selecting the range of address from 200 to 259 and the values of device (voltage, current) are correct with slight adjustment of 0.5 & 0.1 in terms of coeficients. Then I move further by selecting range of addresses from 260 to 320 to read values of energy analyzer (power, frequency, powerfactor) I get correct values again with some slight coefficient adjustments of 0.01 and 0.05.
In case of Modpoll software ,the problem occurs when I make the address selection from 200 to 400. All the values gets disturb and that is why i am declaring them "wrong value". Secondly in case of Sungrow Data logger Software, I will have a google drive folder containing some images for reference.
*Edit @10-04-2024 9:27 GMT
Specifically i am only reading a few register unable to identify whether it exceeds 120 bytes. The modbus address relevant to me are from 200 to 213, 275 to 281 and lastly 416.  I have tried using this way as well by using some Registers for example:
Reading
200.  Phase A L-N Voltage
201.  Phase B L-N Voltage
202.  Phase C L-N Voltage
276.  Frequency
416.  KWh
But the values are not as per the Energy Analyzer.
But as soon as i remove the 276 address (By unchecking the check-box reference to pictures in Google drive), the readings on all other register Address becomes correct and are identical to the values displayed at Energy Analyzer.
Edited 10-04-2024 15:33 GMT
Okay I'll try changing the register read type. Also i will also try the same thing using Modpoll instead of the sungrow data logger and reach out this forum with the results from it...Thanks for the guidance.... I'll update if anything changes...

Please provide additional details. A link to the device documentation would help, along with information on how how are running (a tool? code?), the Modbus queries and the results received ("become instantly wrong" does not really tell us much). Modbus queries can only request a range (e.g. start at Reg 200 and give me 20 registers), so a single command cannot give you 200-212 and 270-278 (unless you request the full range 200-278).

When you say the values are wrong, do you mean they're are literally wrong (from value 10 to 20) or is there a Modbus error?
If it's a Modbus error, I agree with @Brits, you should separate the reading into the two commands, one for each range of values (200-212, 270-278).
You can also test with another tool (like Modbus Poll), to see if it's an issue with your Master.

Please edit the question instead of adding details in the comments (which are hard to read). I have tried to do this for you (you can delete your comments above). Please be specific in your question (i.e. requested register 260 and got the value X but expected Y because...". There is a warning in the manual "Maximum 120 byte can be read in one lot/block" which may be part of the issue (it does not say what happens if a larger block is requested) so see if you get the expected values when reading, say, 50 or fewer registers per request (some devices do not fully follow the Modbus standard).

Please try changing the readtype used on register 276 (my guess, I've not used Sungrow products, and the manual is not that clear) that it's requesting registers 200-276 to get the data you want (and that exceeds the 120 byte limit mentioned in the meter manual). Unfortunately that's all I'm going to be able to suggest (may be able to help further with info from Modpoll as I'm more familiar with that).

Just FYI - things like your latest update are fine as a comment. The aim is to have a question that includes all relevant info so someone looking for the first time can quickly see all relevant info.
